# Character attacks sometimes collide when collision isn't taking place. - Unity Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 3D top down game in Unity 2021.3.4f1 (HDRP).  In the game I have a player character that's already placed in the game scene before it starts and enemy characters that are instantiated at random spawn points within a certain distance of the player.  The enemies and player can use melee attacks to attack each other.  Once in a blue moon the player attacks will hit an enemy that the attacks aren't colliding with.  This also happens vice versa, where an enemy's attacks will hit the player when the colliders aren't colliding.  Otherwise the attacks and collision work flawlessly.  I'm 90% sure that this wasn't occurring before I upgraded the engine from a prior 2019 version.  Any ideas to as why this could be happening?

I'm using an attack pooling system, where attacks are created with their set info (i.e. attack damage, how many characters can be hit with a single attack etc.) and then thrown into a pool of attack objects.  After the attack is registered and has finished, it's deregistered and kept in the pool for further use.  I'm using a bool return method called IsCollided that takes in the attacks information as a parameter to detect the collision:

```
private bool IsCollided(AttackInfo info)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<TriggerDetector, List<Collider>> data in 
        control.animationProgress.CollidingBodyParts)
        {
            foreach (Collider collider in data.Value)
            {
                foreach (AttackPartType part in info.AttackParts)
                {
                    if (info.Attacker.GetAttackingPart(part) == collider.gameObject)
                    {
                        //We want to get the attack scriptable object
                        control.animationProgress.Attack = info.AttackAbility;
                        //We also want to get the attacker
                        control.animationProgress.Attacker = info.Attacker;
                        //We also want to get the damaged trigger
                        control.animationProgress.DamagedTrigger = data.Key;
                        //And then we return true because the attack has collided 
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Otherwise it hasn't collided
        return false;
    }
```

Basically what I'm trying to say is that attacks will sometimes trigger hit reactions when they're not actually colliding with another character. you could be 15 feet away from a character and you'll collide with them. Most of the time it works when it should. But on a rare occasion this issue occurs.

I'm using a "TriggerDetector.cs" script that has an OnTriggerEnter() method that stores all of the collisions that interact with each character's colliders in a list. Those are then removed from the list using an OnTriggerExit() method that removes the collided with objects when the collision is no longer occurring. Aside from that there's tons of checks which detect if the attack is allowed to collide. There's no issues with that though as the attacks always collide when they should be aside from this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but because of my bad English I can't understand this part: "Once in a blue moon the player attacks will hit an enemy that the attacks aren't colliding with. This also happens vice versa, where an enemy's attacks will hit the player when the colliders aren't colliding. Otherwise the attacks and collision work flawlessly. ". Could you try to write it better? The problem is that they can attack even if they don't collide? However, your code is interesting: you can see that you have been working for years :)

Comment: I suspect you’ll need to provide more details about how you’re detecting collisions etc for people to be able to help you. As is there’s just not enough to work with here.

Comment: @iFralex basically what I'm trying to say is that attacks sometimes trigger hit reactions when they're not actually colliding with another character.  you could be 15 feet away from a character and you'll collide with them.  Most of the time it works when it should.  But on a rare occasion this issue occurs.

Comment: @AdamB So I should have mentioned I'm using a "TriggerDetector.cs" script that has an OnTriggerEnter() method that stores all of the collisions that interact with each character's colliders in a list.  Those are then removed from the list using an OnTriggerExit() method that removes the collided with objects when the collision is no longer occurring.  Aside from that there's tons of checks which detect if the attack is allowed to collide.  There's no issues with that though as the attacks always collide. Sometimes they're colliding from a distance when they shouldn't be.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the necessary details :) then people will have a better chance of knowing how to help you.

Comment: @AdamB When this happens enemies will take damage and have hit reactions without actually being hit.  This will only happen when attacks are active and not hitting.

Comment: @AdamB May I ask what extra details you're asking for?  Everything I've just shared is what's relevant to collision detection.  I'm thinking it has something to do with collider sizing or something with collision in the project setting rather than the actual code, as I stated previously this happened when updating the engine.

Comment: What I mean is to edit your question rather than put it in comments. That way newcomers can read the full story and potentially understand it better to help you. Comments are typically only read by people who have an idea of what the problem already is.

Comment: @AdamB I see, will do.

Comment: Could it be that when the object is sent to the pool, it collides with everything between the unit & the pool? Coninuous collision detection, checking for objects between positions?

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that your system for adding and removing colliders may not work in all cases.
Specifically, I believe that ontriggerexit is not always called correctly, or there is some other problem in the method which, however, I cannot see because you have not published it.
I can advise you to use a different system: instead of using collisions, you can check every frame or every short time with a coroutine, if there are enemies within your area.
To do this, you can study how circles work in mathematics and how you can use them to check if an object is within the area around you.
Since 2019 Unity has made many changes and has probably changed, perhaps making it worse, the collision system.
If you need help with the advice on using the circumference, I can help you, perhaps by opening another question.
If I helped you, you could thank me by marking my answer as accepted: I would be grateful :)
P.S.  Instead of foreach use for - it's much better for performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm going to look more closely at the list of added collisions to see what's being added when this bug occurs.  I'll get back to you soon.